# dmesg: klogctl: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, permissions

I see the following error running dmesg in my Linux running on a embedded board (Qualcomm RB5). The Linux is built using Yocto.

```
/ # dmesg
dmesg: klogctl: Operation not permitted
```

As you see, I'm running as root. I am also aware of the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390184/dmesg-read-kernel-buffer-failed-permission-denied). But when I issue the solution given there I get the following error:

```
/ # echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/dmesg_restrict
sh: write error: Operation not permitted
```

Any idea how should I get around with it?

Comment: Is CONFIG_SECURITY_DMESG_RESTRICT flag disabled in your kernel defconfig?